# How to import Scale type definition from Scale module?

Tags: typescript, types, tonal.js

I'm using the package [Tonal](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal) in a Vite/Vue/Typescript project.

I'm trying to import the type defined as `Scale` within the `Scale` module.

The type is defined [here](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal) like this:

```
export interface Scale extends ScaleType {
  tonic: string | null;
  type: string;
  notes: NoteName[];
}
```

The module itself is exported like this:

```
export default {
  degrees,
  detect,
  extended,
  get,
  modeNames,
  names,
  rangeOf,
  reduced,
  scaleChords,
  scaleNotes,
  steps,
  tokenize,

  // deprecated
  scale,
};
```

and imported like:

```
import { Scale } from "tonal";
```

So how can I import the type?

Attempts like this don't work:

```
import type { Scale } from 'tonal'
import type { Scale.Scale } from 'tonal'
import type { Scale } from 'tonal/packages/scale'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal/tree/main/packages/scale) of the `scale` package from that project, you can install the `@tonaljs/scale` project and import from that.

This would import from what [this file](https://github.com/tonaljs/tonal/blob/main/packages/scale/index.ts) exports.

Meaning the type you want is at:

```
import { Scale } from "@tonaljs/scale"
```

Which [works as you expect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBDAnmApnA3nAygYwIYA2aAvnAGZQQhwBEAAjBAHaEBWAzgPTv5E0DcAKEEATFDgJ4oaHM3bwehFAC5svFIMVEAdEwgwU7QZ05wzcAHoB+IA)

---

You will have to explicitly add `@tonaljs/scale` in your npm dependencies to make it available for import, but according to [the dependencies of `tonal`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tonal?activeTab=dependencies) it already installs that for you. Making it an explicit dependency just tells Typescript that you are allowed to import from it directly.